# Slack and github integration: start receiving updates for tasks in a github project for status changes on a single slack channel

Tags: github, slack, agile-project-management, agile-processes, github-projects

We use slack for internal communication in our team and have configured github on slack for getting updates about new commits and issues. Now, we want our workstream to be managed by tasks in github projects and for this need to configure a slack channel for receiving updates about the tasks being created, assigned, completed or any other status change on a task need to be notified over the same slack channel. Like we do it for commits and issues. I have searched for having it done but, nowhere I found how can one do this.

Here are the references I have gone through, they only suggest slack and github integration for - commits, issues, pull requests, status check on pull requests, code reviews and deployments :

https://slack.github.com/

https://github.com/integrations/slack

https://github.blog/2019-07-29-whats-new-in-the-github-and-slack-integration/

https://slack.com/intl/en-in/help/articles/232289568-GitHub-for-Slack

Is the feature available that I am looking for, or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after contacting Github support I got a confirmation from them that the feature is not available presently and they are not working on this feature as well. To request this feature,

https://github.com/integrations/slack/issues/699

is the link to existing issue and number of reactions on this will help them to prioritize work in the future.